# How to get the callback to viewmodel from library

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have a UIControl(LatestHeadline) in a view(Home.xaml)(there are around 10 more controls on the same page) which is a textblock.I want to set the text of this control when user clicks on a button(named "Retrieve") from the same view.I have to call the method in utilities library from my viewmodel .The method(GetLatestHeadline) in the utilitieslibrary connects to a web api through webclient class and it fires the (deleagate)method Retrieve_Completed event.

Once this event is completed the required data is retrieved from eventargs paramater e.Now from the utilitieslibrary I want to return the data to the viewmodel so that the I can bind this to the LatestHeadline textblock.

LatestHeadline textblock has binding to a property(named "PropHeadLine") defined in viewmodel.
Is there a way we can achieve this in C#.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the concept of a "callback" for this kind of thing -- specifically, pass an `Action<string>` from the View Model to the service.  The service can then save a reference to the callback, or pass it along to the completed-handler in the "UserState".  So, the utilities method would look something like this:

```
public void GetLatestHeadline(Action<string> callback)
{
    _apiClient.Retrieve(userState: callback);
}

private void Retrieve_Completed(object sender, RetrieveCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var callback = args.UserState as Action<string>;
    if (callback != null)
        callback(args.Result.Headline);
}
```

Now the view model can pass a callback to the utilities method -- the callback should presumably just set the property "PropHeadLine" to the result value:

```
private void Button_Click()
{
    Utilities.GetLatestHeadline( result => PropHeadLine = result );
}
```

Comment: I am using a WebClient to access the data from the API and I always get the e.UserSTate as null with DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the utility class from the view model, then surely you can just add a handler to your `Retrieve_Completed` `delegate` in the view model.

```
utilityClass.Retrieve_Completed += UtilityClassRetrieve_Completed;
utilityClass.GetLatestHeadline();

...

public void UtilityClassRetrieve_Completed(EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with your e.New value here in the view model
    LatestHeadlineProperty = e.New;
}
```

Of course, I'm just guessing at what your `Retrieve_Completed` definition is here, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention it. The LatestHeadline has a binding to property defined in the ViewModel.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Did this suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Expose a Delegate or Event in your service, in your view model just subscribe or hook to 
   that delegate or event
2. when ever you want to notify the viewmodel Once a particular operation is completed, just invoke the delegate or event
3. The method which is hooked in your viewmodel will get called.
4. In your viewmodel now you can do the necessary actions you want